# How can I set up a redirect with Zeit's Now 2.0?

Tags: vercel, zeit-pkg

Currently I'm trying to redirect from root.com/robots.txt to beta.root.com/robots.txt.

This is not working currently, any idea why?:

```
{
  "version": 2,
  "alias": ["root.com"],
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/(.*)",
      "status": 301,
      "headers": { "Location": "https://beta.root.com/$1" },
      "dest": "/$1"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not use `dest` if you don't plan on proxy/rewriting requests.

Since you want the client to redirect, all you need is the header.

```json
{
  "version": 2,
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/robots.txt",
      "status": 301,
      "headers": { "Location": "https://beta.root.com/robots.txt" }
    }
  ]
}
```

If you want to redirect everything, use a wildcard:

```json
{
  "version": 2,
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "(.*)",
      "status": 301,
      "headers": { "Location": "https://beta.root.com$1" }
    }
  ]
}
```

[View Documentation](https://vercel.com/docs/configuration#project/routes)

### Update 2020

You can now use `redirects` which is a little easier.

```json
{
  "redirects": [
    { "source": "(.*)", "destination": "https://beta.root.com$1" }
  ]
}
```

[View Documentation](https://vercel.com/docs/configuration#project/redirects)

Comment: Hi @styfle ... maybe you can help me .. I'm trying to do proxy  My API it's running under `https://my-api.com/test.json`   the app it's making request to `/api/test.json`   so... how can I configure vercel ?

That's it's what I have so far...
------------------

```
"redirects": [
        {
            "source": "/api/menu.json",
            "destination": "https://chatfood-cdn.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/fe-code-challenge-1/menu.json",
        }
    ],
    "rewrites": [
        {
            "source": "/(.*)",
            "destination": "/index.html"
        }
    ]
```

Comment: Do you know, do I have to set wildcard domain in Vercel to apply redirect? I get `DEPLOYMENT_NOT_FOUND` error. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73031660/how-to-configure-arbitrary-subdomain-to-be-able-to-use-in-vercel